# Isotope grid layout fails first time

Tags: jquery-isotope

The Isotope grid is wrong the first time I access to it. There are two screen captures to compare.

1. First time (or accessing without browser cache):

[image: page look at first time access]

2. Second time access (or simple browser reload):

[image: page look at second time access]

This can be seen at: http://telmo.club/merz/

Isotope js init:

```
init: function() {
        // init Isotope
        var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
          // options
          layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        });
        // filter items on button click
        $('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
          var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
          $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
          $('.grid').isotope({
            hiddenStyle: {
              opacity: 0
            },
            visibleStyle: {
              opacity: 1
            }
          });
        });
      }
```

What am I doing wong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your codes inside `$(window).load()`:

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
          // options
          layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        });
        // filter items on button click
        $('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
          var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
          $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
          $('.grid').isotope({
            hiddenStyle: {
              opacity: 0
            },
            visibleStyle: {
              opacity: 1
            }
          });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got a lot of jshint errors (with document ready function I got the same errors). The first error is "'function closure expressions' is only available in Mozilla JavaScript extensions (use moz option)". It exceed my basic knowledge of coding!

Comment: Sorry, was my fault. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much.